# Jira OAuth - Unable to create application link

Tags: java, oauth, rsa, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to create an application which uses jira for authentication. I am using [Jira Rest api](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication) for the same. In the documentation it says to use the same public key and consumer-key to create application link as given in the doc. This works fine, and I am able to create access-token. But in java code as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10701515/oauth-authentication-in-jira-by-using-java), I am not sure what should be given for private_key. I tried two methods-

1. Generated a random private key using rsa and provided it in place of private_key which didn't work. It gave exception telling `length too long`. I tried for 2048, 1024, 512, 256 and 128 bits. Everything gave same error.

Application link:

Consumer-key: hardcoded-consumer

Consumer Name: hardcoded-consumer

Public Key: 
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAxZDzGUGk6rElyPm0iOua0lWg84nOlhQN1gmTFTIu5WFyQFHZF6OA4HX7xATttQZ6N21yKMakuNdRvEudyN/coUqe89r3Ae+rkEIn4tCxGpJWX205xVF3Cgsn8ICj6dLUFQPiWXouoZ7HG0sPKhCLXXOvUXmekivtyx4bxVFD9Zy4SQ7IHTx0V0pZYGc6r1gF0LqRmGVQDaQSbivigH4mlVwoAO9Tfccf+V00hYuSvntU+B1ZygMw2rAFLezJmnftTxPuehqWu9xS5NVsPsWgBL7LOi3oY8lhzOYjbMKDWM6zUtpOmWJA52cVJW6zwxCxE28/592IARxlJcq14tjwYwIDAQAB

2. Generated private and public key pair and provided the same in application link and in code respectively. But in this case, I am unable to create access token. It is giving -

Application link:

Consumer-key: hardcoded-consumer

Consumer Name: hardcoded-consumer

Public Key: 
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC0YjCwIfYoprq/FQO6lb3asXrx LlJFuCvtinTF5p0GxvQGu5O3gYytUvtC2JlYzypSRjVxwxrsuRcP3e641SdASwfr mzyvIgP08N4S0IFzEURkV1wp/IpH7kH41EtbmUmrXSwfNZsnQRE5SYSOhh+LcK2w yQkdgcMv11l4KoBkcwIDAQAB

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:340)
    at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to obtain request token
    at com.atlassian.oauth.client.example.AtlassianOAuthClient.getRequestToken(AtlassianOAuthClient.java:66)
    at com.atlassian.oauth.client.example.JIRAOAuthClient.main(JIRAOAuthClient.java:52)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: net.oauth.OAuthProblemException: signature_invalid
    at net.oauth.client.OAuthResponseMessage.toOAuthProblemException(OAuthResponseMessage.java:83)
    at net.oauth.client.OAuthClient.invoke(OAuthClient.java:306)
    at net.oauth.client.OAuthClient.invoke(OAuthClient.java:260)
    at net.oauth.client.OAuthClient.getRequestTokenResponse(OAuthClient.java:190)
    at com.atlassian.oauth.client.example.AtlassianOAuthClient.getRequestToken(AtlassianOAuthClient.java:57)
```

Can someone explain me what should be done? Am I missing something here?
And also what is the difference between shared key, consumer key and public key?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If I remember correctly you should use private key in your client application to sign requests. Of course you need a pair of private and public keys that match. Unfortunately I don't know Java api since I used .NET

Comment: Tnx for the reply @Robert . I have fixed the issue somehow and have posted the answer

Answer (score 1):

The exception occurs due to ending with "/" in JIRA base URL (caused by `net.oauth.OAuthProblemException: signature_invalid`).

The correct request is:

```
java -jar rest-oauth-client-1.0.one-jar.jar requestToken https://jira_base_server_url http://your_redirctedUrl
```

Answer (score -1):

I somehow fixed the issue by using the public that is provided in the [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-oauth-authentication) and the private key as given in the [example](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/files/6291692/rest-oauth-client-1.0-sources.jar)

But still, I was unable to create an application link with private and public key generated by me.